# How can I compare two fields from two different tables with mysql?

Tags: mysql

Something just like this

```
select 
(
case when     
( (select t1.name from table_1 as t1)=(select t2.name from table_2 as t2) )    
then 'same'    
else 'different'     
end
);
```

I want to compare 'name' from table_1 with the 'name' from table_2 and if they are equals it shows in the field "same name" and if not, it shows "not the same".

There's any kind of `case` (or anything else) that I can do that?

I will have to do this with multiple fields (name, last name, age, etc...), and I just can't figure this simple query out.

---

Here's another comparison that i want but now with two columns:

```
    Table A:
 ID - NAME - Age
 1    rick   12
 2    denis  21
 3    jane   34
 4    john   38
 5    jerry  76
 6    max    54

    Table B:
 ID - NAME - Age
 1    rick   10
 2    jay    21
 3    morris 34
 4    john   38
 5    jerry  79
 6    morty  54
```

Result from comparing each field with the condition that i want:

```
ID -   Name     -  Age
1     Same        Different
2     Different   Same
3     Different   Same
4     Same        Same
5     Same        Different
6     Different   Same
```

Comment: What would it even mean though. You want to compare EVERY name from table_1 with EVERY name from table_2. That would result in table_1-RowCount * table_2-RowCount number of results. For instance if your tables both had a 10000 names in them, your result would be 100,000,000 records. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question though. Please add some sample data and desired results so we can understand better what you are after.

Comment: The tables only have 1 row in each of them? If they have multiple rows, is there a relationship between the rows that you want to compare?

Comment: If there's a relationship, join the tables using that column and compare the names.

Comment: @JNevill Both tables have more than 190k records, I want to compare the records from table_a with table_b, by selecting all fields from table_a and table_b. I will make a better explanation of what i want to, i will edit my post

Comment: @Barmar They don't have any relation with each other.

Comment: Add a sample of 10 rows from each table, and show what you would expect the result to be.

Comment: Short story: I have a huge csv file, lets call it 'data_a.csv' with 190k records from today, and i will have to compare this 'data_a.csv' with another 'data_b.csv' from the last day. I already managed to load the data to the right tables, 'data_a.csv' to table_a and 'data_b.csv' to table_b, now i need to compare if had any changes from yesterday to today by comparing the fields, just the way i explaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this will help

```
 SELECT CASE 
             WHEN t2.name IS NULL THEN 'not the same' 
             ELSE 'same name' 
         END 
    FROM table_1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, actually this is exactly what i need from the first example, but what about the other ones (i updated), but now with the age.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, it was needed to have a relation between tables, so there it goes:

Table 1

```
create table table1 (
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(40),
    age int,
    primary key (id)
    );
```

Table 2

```
create table table2 (
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(40),
    age int,
    primary key (id),
    CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`)
);
```

Insert some data in both tables...

```
insert into table1 (name,age) values
('morty',14),
('rick',70),
('beth',35);

insert into table2 (name,age) values
('morty',14),
('rick',50),
('beeth',35);
```

Query that i wanted:

```
(select  t1.name as t1name,t2.name as t2name,
 (case
  when t1.name = t2.name then 'same' else 'dif'
 end) as resultName, t1.age as age1,t2.age as age2,
 (case
  when t1.age = t2.age then 'same' else 'dif'
 end) as resultAge
 from table1 as t1
 left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 )
  order by t1name,t2name;
```

Result:

```
t1name  t2name  resultName    age1  age2  resultage
beth    beeth   dif           35    35    same
morty   morty   same          14    14    same
rick    rick    same          70    50    dif
```